# Asp.net returning "True"

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my controller I am returning boolean true or false and check it in my JavaScript.

I realized that I am getting "True" instead of true and same for false.

I don't want to check on my client side result == "True". Any way around this?

```
    public async Task<bool> Send(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            return await RystadGlobal.api.ContactSupport(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }

        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/ClientHelpPage/Send',
        data: data,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            if (data == true) {
                success.removeClass("hide");
            } else {
                error.removeClass("hide");
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            error.removeClass("hide");

        }
    });
```

Comment: When you send value over network, its transmitted in string. hence `"True"`. Instead, try using numeric values: `0` as false and `1` as true. That way, you can check for `if(parseInt(data)) { ... }`

Comment: @Rajesh that solved the issue. Thanks. And I did learned why it was sending it like that.

Comment: @Mamun `Boolean("False")` would return `true`

Comment: Glad I was able to help! I have faced this issue where you have values are in following format `"True"/"False"`, `true/false`, `"0"/"1"` and `0/1` and it was a BIG pain.\